# How to retain parameters set with scope = memory during reboot in Oracle

Tags: oracle, memory, parameters, scope

One of my Oracle server has few parameters set earlier with scope = memory. I don't know which parameters as well as there values as the person who set it has left the organization. That server now needs a reboot. I want to retain those parameter values even after reboot.
Is there any way to retain those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (re-)[create an `spfile`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/statements_6016.htm) from the current memory settings:

```
create spfile from memory;
```